# If $Ax+By=c$ represents a linear quation. What is $c$ in this equation and what does it represent intuitively?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

When we write down the simultaneous equations in the form of $Ax=b$ what does the elements in vector $b$ tell us intuitively?

Comment: What do you mean by *simultaneous equations*. There is a single one.

Comment: "what does it represent intuitively?"  Nothing. For one thing, you could multiply the equation by $2$, and you'd get the same line. It's hard to see if you are asking a homework question without even thinking of it, or if it's a genuine doubt.

Comment: $c$ represents the addition of $Ax + By.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the question in the title, we have $$Ax+By=C\implies y=\frac CB-\frac AB x$$ so $C/B$ is the intercept. The point $(0, C/B)$ is precisely where the line crosses the $y$-axis.

Say we have the system of equations $$\alpha x+\beta y=\gamma\\\delta x+\epsilon y=\theta$$ yielding the form $$\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\\delta&\epsilon\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\gamma\\\theta\end{bmatrix}.$$ Note that the vector $b=[\gamma\quad\theta]^T$ does not have much meaning in itself.

Comment: "C  is the intercept" , uhmm no. UNless $B=1$

Comment: @leonbloy Edited.

Comment: Be careful with division. Vertical line has $B=0$.

Comment: @Sigur I think the OP is more concerned with the equation when $y$ is part of it; otherwise it is very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

In the equation of a line in standard form. $a x + by = c.$ 
$c$ is a scaled distance from the origin.  $\frac {|c|}{\sqrt {a^2+b^2}}$ is the actual distance from the origin.

As far as what $b$ means intuitively in a system of equations $Ax = b,$ where $x$ and $b$ are vectors. I don't have much for you.

To some degree $\|b\|$ has some relation to $\|x\|$ but it depends on the magnitude of the eigenvalues of $A.$  So, that is not much to go on.